# After discovering alpha error inflation, how to estimate severity of the effect?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, multiple-comparisons, bonferroni, false-discovery-rate

**Example:** I find alpha inflation in an already published report. 300 indicators had been independently tested for statistical significance, and the "significant" results then reported as 95% confident without adjusted p-values. Multiple findings have already been taken as a fact, and decisions have been made based on that. **What is the best way to quantify the severity of the problem, and make the severity of the effect intuitively understandable?**.

I am aware of **Sidak, Bonferonni, and False discovery rate, but** they appear to be, at least primarily, ways to readjust the threshold for accepting the null hypothesis. In this context type II error cost is important, so simply adjusting the p-value doesn't fix the issue. The question is with regard to the general methodology of "blindly" measuring and testing as much as possible. How can the total risk of both errors be *quantified* in an intuitively understandable metric, in comparison for example to a more focused study with strong hypotheses.

Comment: It would help to know more about how those 300 tests came to be. How are they or aren't they related? What do they represent? The issue of whether FWER is necessary to adjust for depends on it. (Adjusting for FWER when not needed would destroy statistical power)

Comment: a large scale population survey with 300 questions conducted in three different geographical areas. Some of the questions are probably correlated, some are not. Chi square tests are performed on all questions indipendently, looking for significant differences in the population of the different geographical areas

Answer (score 1):

It's possible there may be little problem at all; the 5% type I error rate means that *of the nulls that were true* 5% of those would be incorrectly rejected, but it's quite possible that none of the nulls were true. If considerably more than 5% of tests resulted in significance that would suggest that type I errors were not likely to be a major cause of rejections.

You'll likely want to at least mention that there's a risk that a number of the rejections may be type I errors, but aside from noting that it will be - at most - about 5% of the tests performed (and then only if there were no correct rejections at all), it may not require saying much more.

If you have access to the p-values, you could perhaps point out that the ones with p-values not substantially less than 5% would be one that would not have been rejected if the rate had been lowered to account for overall type I error.

However since decisions are being based on rejection or non-rejection, note that type II errors carry a cost as well - associated with failing to take whatever action would have been taken if the null had correctly been rejected. As such, lowering the overall type I error rate might in some situations be worse (more costly) in terms of the overall numbers and types of the two kinds of error.

Concern with familywise error rates perhaps makes some sense in a scientific context where type I errors loom large and someone may be trying to avoid much chance of making more than one across a large study with many tests; it may make less sense in (say) a business context to focus so hard on them.

Indeed, if the choice of 5% was based on a suitably selected tradeoff in the two error rates (I'd bet it wasn't, but *if*), then it would actually be better not to try to correct for familywise error because that would actually ruin the per-test tradeoff that was made.

In short: I'd advise a cautious response rather than a strong one. Don't focus only on overall type I error but consider also the effect on power (and its complement, type II error), and if possible the likely costs of the two errors (as well, if it's possible, the extent to which it's really plausible your nulls are actually exactly true -- one sided nulls may be, but exact truth of point nulls should be considered very carefully -- in many situations it's likely none are true).

For all you know at the moment, the best tradeoff between the two error types*  across all of those tests would have been to raise, rather than lower the significance level.

*(if choosing a single significance level for all of them -- not necessarily the wisest course)

Comment: (+1) "If considerably more than 5% of tests resulted in significance that would suggest that type I errors were not likely to be a major cause of rejections." — Suppose 24 of 100 null hypotheses are rejected. I agree that it's very unlikely that all those rejections are type-I errors, but isn't it still plausible that a substantial fraction of them are type-I errors? For example, 20 of the overall hypotheses might've been correctly rejected whereas the other 80 are true, and the remaining 4 rejections (5% of 80) are type-I errors.

Comment: I don't think we'd be disagreeing over anything other than how much more "considerably more" is and how major "major" might be.

Comment: Fair enough. :)

Comment: "In short: I'd advise a cautious response rather than a strong one. Don't focus only on overall type I error but consider also the effect on power " Wouldn't that in most cases come down to, and rightly be perceived as, not a cautious response but a doubly scathing response: Not only did you inflate your type I errors, but on top of that you don't care about type II errors and have no clue about power analysis!

Comment: No, the advice about considering type II errors was to the OP, not the people the OP worries have made an error in leaving the significance level at 5% for all tests. In considering type II errors (and their costs), one may be less inclined to insist that the overall type I error rate should be (say) 5% (giving a per test rate of say 0.00017 ... with corresponding effect on type II error)

Comment: Well aware of that and there is merit in not assuming the worst from people. However there is a trade-off, at a certain point you are just deluding yourself and harming everybody by ignoring obvious problems. (There might still be an issue with being able to speak truth to power, but that's separate.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you're suggesting there. Who do you think is deluding themselves in which way?

Comment: I'm suggesting that if a paper does 300 comparisons, never mentions FWER corrections (not even to say why they shouldn't apply) and never mentions power considerations nor the trade-off between both issues, it is delusional to think they considered all those issues carefully but never wrote them down. Those authors careful enough to consider all these issues would know it is important to lay out their reasoning. If none of this can be found, it is safe to assume none of this was considered. There is still a separate question of how to tell them *diplomatically* that they screwed up.

Comment: The OP calls the document a report. It doesn't sound like a journal article (but perhaps I misconstrue); imperatives may differ somewhat. Even if they didn't consider those things (and I agree they should have), the point in my answer is that it's not automatically the case that they did worse by (perhaps) blindly doing so than they would by blindly restricting the overall error rate to 5%. (I definitely understand that you're not suggesting that they should have done that either -- I don't see any substantive disagreement between us about what better practice would be.)

Comment: @Kodiologist so do I understand correctly that I need to use the total number of significant results if I want to quantify the issue? What would be the correct way to combine the number of tests, the pvalue threshold and the total number of rejected nulls to get a number that intuitively shows whether this is a problem or not?

Comment: @Glen_b  edited the question based on your comments. Yes, type II is important in this case! thats why I tried to clarify that I am not looking for p-value threshold adjustment methods. But generally the broad approach led to less useful p-values than they would have achieved in a more focused study right? *I want to be able to give a quantitative indication of how much we can actually trust the reported results.* Apart from that, do I understand correctly that I need to read up on power analysis and effect size? *What other googable concepts are crucial* in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know that trying to conduct power analysis after the fact is necessarily the ideal approach and it's certainly not sufficient (although it would help to inform the considerations I was going on about). Where you can formulate appropriate ideas of effects it might be useful. But there's other considerations I mentioned - getting a rough upper bound on the number of type I errors (as per kodi's style of calculation); identifying implausible point nulls (e.g. "is it plausible males and females have *identical* population mean?" would probably be answered "well, no"), ... ctd

Comment: ctd... which completely negate the need for looking at power, and there's little point worrying about any of this is you can't compare the costs (and approximate relative prior probabilities) of the null and various effect sizes at least in a roughly reasonable way (you might be able to consider some "best" and "worst" cases perhaps). But even if you can't get far with power analysis and those costs and probabilities, some of the other considerations will give some idea of whether there's all that much to worry about.

Comment: Note that if 100% of your nulls were true, you'd expect 15 rejections (all type I). If you had 100 rejections in the worst case you'd expect 11 of them would be type I errors. If you had 150 rejections in the worst case you'd expect 8 of them to be type I. At 200 rejections you'd expect about 5 type I errors under the worst case. Add in the "how plausible is a point null for this test" considerations and those (modest) numbers may be way too high; even without considering power you may not have much to worry about.

Comment: @Glen_b your last comment is almost exactly the answer to my question _"How can the total risk of both errors be quantified.."_.. I should be able to estimate the expected % of type I errors among all rejected nulls from the number of rejected nulls, the number of tests and the global p-value right? Similar thing could work for type II?  could you add that to your answer?